# Is Micrometer's Meter Registry is non-blocking?

Tags: kotlin, metrics, micrometer

I'm using `io.micrometer:micrometer-core:1.8.3` jar. I'm publishing counter metrics using MeterRegistry class. I'm calling `counter().increment()` in a void function using Kotlin with **micronaut** framework.

My concerns after reading the class level comment:

> *MeterRegistry may be used in a reactive context. As such, implementations must not negatively impact the calling thread, e.g. it should respond immediately by avoiding IO call, deep stack recursion or any coordination.*

1. Is there a specific way we need to write the method which calls `counter().increment()`?
2. Is publishing metrics using meter registry considered an I/O operation? I'm not able to read any docs as to how the same metric name would be changed by multiple threads

Comment: That comment is a warning to people creating their own implementations of `MeterRegistry`. As an ordinary user of Micrometer, it is safe to update metrics in a reactive/non-blocking context. The comment explicitly gives you permission to do this.

Comment: @dnault I'm not calling the `increment()` function in a reactive manner.

Comment: I think you misunderstood the comment. It answers both your questions. It explicitly says the metrics function should not do any I/O underneath. No, you don't have to use it in any specific way.